# Remove substring of string

Tags: c

So i was doing some coding exercice on Talentbuddy (for those who know), and i cant get why i cant finish this one.
The exercice is removing a substring from a string, given as input the string, the position P where beginning to remove characters and N the number of characters needed to be remove.

Here is what i've done :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void remove_substring(char *s, int p, int n) 
{
    int idx;

    idx = -1;
    while (s[++idx] != '\0')
       write(1, &s[idx == p - 1 ? idx + n : idx], 1);
}
```

When the input is "abcdefghi", P = 9 and N = 1, the result given is "abcdefgh" exactly the same as the one i get with my function. But TalentBuddy keep saying me that my output is wrong and i dont thing he (talentbuddy) is wrong.
Maybe there is a blank space or something between the "h" and the '\0'. 
But i cant figure it cause when i add another write(1, "END", 3) at the end it appears like "abcdefghEND".

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code. The importance of being able to debug effectively cannot be overstated.

Comment: I would do it if i wasnt at work :(

Comment: Hey Robin, I'm your boss, and you're fired for playing with Talentbuddy during work hours :)

Comment: Why are you using `write` to output to `stdout`? Why not just use `printf` or `puts`? And it's unclear what you're saying your problem is.

Comment: What is your question? If you get the required result then what's the problem?

Comment: Edit : Talentbuddy keep telling me that i'm wrong

Comment: Shouldn't that be "idx >= p - 1"? Otherwise it will only skip one character when you're printing. And if you do a write(1, "END", 3) then that's the correct output. Also, why are you using write?

Comment: Both printf and putchar use the system call write to work, so there is (i think) no difference. Its just a question of preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you write something for every original index, even if it should be suppressed. What you write looks like `abcdefgh`, but it is `abcdefgh<nul>`, where the terminal doesn't render the `<nul>`.

You are mixing two methods here. Either filter out the removed substring:

```
void remove_substring(char *s, int p, int n) 
{
    int i = 0;

    p--;        /* convert to C-style index */

    while (s[i] != '\0') {
       if (i < p || i >= p + n) putchar(s[i]);
       i++;
    }
}
```

or skip the substring by jumping over it:

```
void remove_substring(char *s, int p, int n) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int l = strlen(s);

    while (i < l) {
        if (i + 1 == p) {
            i += n;
        } else {
            putchar(s[i++]);
        }
    }
}
```

You're trying to do a bit of both.

(I've avoided the awkward combination of prefix increment and starting at minus 1. And I've used `putchar` instead of `unistd`'s write. And the termination by length is so you don't inadvertently jump beyond the terminating `<nul>`.)

Answer (score 1):

If the question is exclusively for strings( NULL Terminated )
Why can't this be as simple as this, unless it is a homework.

```
void removesubstr( const char *string, const char *substring )
{
        char *p = strstr(string, substring);
        if(p)
        {
                strcpy(p,p+strlen(substring));
        }
}
```